# Flutter: how to maintain TextField value after dismissing the soft Keyboard

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

There is a simple structure with a Bottom Modal Sheet that contains an input TextField to add a Text into a List and a button to submit the value.

When the text field is focused, it automatically opens the soft keyboard that covers the submit button.
When I dismiss the keyboard in order to press the button, the value in the text field is still visible but the sent value is null. 
If I press the button without dismissing the keyboard, the value is correctly sent.

The question is: how can I dismiss the keyboard and still be able to send the typed value after pressing the submit button?

Here is the code:

1) On the main screen, the floating action button shows the modal bottom sheet.

```
return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen(),               
      },
```

2) On the AddTaskScreen class, there is a Column with the content of the modal bottom sheet inside a container.

```
Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Add your next Task',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            autofocus: true,
            onChanged: (value) {
              newTaskTitle = value;
            },
          ),
          FlatButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'ADD',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 25,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            onPressed: () {
              print(newTaskTitle);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

In this simplified version, the value from the TextField is printed in the console when pressing the button. If I press the button without hiding the keyboard it works fine; If I hide the keyboard it passes a null value.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue, I resolved it by simply converting called class to extend `StatefullWidget` instead of `StatelessWidget`.

In your case converting class `AddTaskScreen()` to extend `StatefullWidget`.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, this worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the easiest way to do this is by supplying a TextEditingController to the child class.

So for your case, you can first create a TextEditingController in the Parent Class, then pass it to the child class. And in the TextField inside child class set the controller: The controller you have passed

```
Parent Class.....
//// other codes ////
TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
return Scafold{
  FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AddTaskScreen(textEditingController),               
  },
};
```

And in the child class

```
class ChildClass extends StatelessWidget(
final TextEditingController textEditingController;
ChildClass({this.textEditingController});
///then inside build method///
Container(
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(
        'Add your next Task',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        ),
      ),
      TextField(
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        autofocus: true,
        controller: textEditingController, /// here add the controller
        onChanged: (value) {
          newTaskTitle = value;
        },
      ),
      FlatButton(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            'ADD',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        onPressed: () {
          print(newTaskTitle);
        },
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Now you can access what was written in the TextField by simply calling textEditingController.value.text from anywhere between these two classes.

Answer (score 1):

Just moving the declarations of text controllers work for me.

```
....    
class _AddPlaceScreenState extends State<AddPlaceScreen> {
      final controllerTittlePlace = TextEditingController();
      final controllerDescriptionPlace = TextEditingController();
      final controllerLocationPlace = TextEditingController();
....
```